# Outlook 2011 crashing constantly (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, mac, email, ms-office, crash

I recently tried to send a video file that was too large via Outlook. Spinning wheel, then Outlook started crashing. Managed eventually to delete the email from my outbox, but Outlook now crashes every time, a couple of minutes after opening.

The error report is pasted below. Any help people can give would be much appreciated!

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Date/Time: 2013-08-27 15:06:57 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Outlook
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Outlook
Application Signature: OPIM
Application Version: 14.1.0.110310
Crashed Module Name: unknown
Crashed Module Version: unknown
Crashed Module Offset: unknown
Blame Module Name: unknown
Blame Module Version: unknown
Blame Module Offset: unknown
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409 
Crashed thread: 0


Thread 0:

#  1  0x9a00d7d2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x99295003 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x02c9468e in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x001266a8 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x02c895e7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x02c89ace in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x00126542 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x0012645f in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  9  0x9101e9b4 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 10  0x94dc7406 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 11  0x94dc6da5 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 12  0x94dabbb2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 13  0x94dab01a in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 14  0x94daae8b in  + 0x0000E7F0 ( + 0x00000000)
# 15  0x90b0bf5a in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 16  0x90b0bcc9 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 17  0x90b0bb44 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 18  0x923f993a in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 19  0x923f916c in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 20  0x000d854a in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 21  0x923ef5cc in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 22  0x923925f6 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 23  0x000d09fa in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0xffffffe1  ebx: 0xbff323e8  ecx: 0xbff3237c  edx:0x9a00d7d2
 edi: 0x00000020  esi: 0x00000003  ebp: 0xbff323b8  esp:0xbff3237c
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00d7d2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000206


Thread 1:

#  1  0x9a0109ae in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x96b037a9 in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0x0000016b  ebx: 0xb0080700  ecx: 0xb00805ac  edx:0x9a0109ae
 edi: 0x00000000  esi: 0x96b038a1  ebp: 0xb0080718  esp:0xb00805ac
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a0109ae   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000246


Thread 2:

#  1  0x9a00d8e6 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x9598b6b6 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x02c7019a in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x02c6f866 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x02c6f7f1 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x02c70d8e in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0xffffffa6  ebx: 0x00000000  ecx: 0xb0288a7c  edx:0x9a00d8e6
 edi: 0x00000184  esi: 0xd8f81714  ebp: 0xb0288ac8  esp:0xb0288a7c
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00d8e6   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000246


Thread 3:

#  1  0x9a00d7d2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x99295003 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x99294e55 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x992950d4 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x02c94d18 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x02c93de2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x02c93beb in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x02c99596 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  9  0x0057ced5 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 10  0x0022c8c2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 11  0x0022d8f1 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 12  0x0022f1ba in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 13  0x004b931d in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 14  0x02c94330 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 15  0x99294c4d in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 16  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 17  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0xffffffe1  ebx: 0xb0594c58  ecx: 0xb0594bec  edx:0x9a00d7d2
 edi: 0x00000020  esi: 0x00000003  ebp: 0xb0594c28  esp:0xb0594bec
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00d7d2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000206


Thread 4:

#  1  0x9a00d7d2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x99295003 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x02c9468e in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x02c94c0b in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x0022d8c0 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x0022f1ba in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x004b931d in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x02c94330 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  9  0x99294c4d in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 10  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 11  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0xffffffe1  ebx: 0xb0698e18  ecx: 0xb0698dac  edx:0x9a00d7d2
 edi: 0x00000020  esi: 0x00000003  ebp: 0xb0698de8  esp:0xb0698dac
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00d7d2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000206


Thread 5:

#  1  0x9a00d7d2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x99295003 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x02c9468e in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x02c93cbf in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x02c9955d in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x0057d106 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x0022c8c2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x0022d8f1 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  9  0x0022f1ba in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 10  0x004b931d in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 11  0x02c94330 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 12  0x99294c4d in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 13  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 14  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0xffffffe1  ebx: 0xb0616ce8  ecx: 0xb0616c7c  edx:0x9a00d7d2
 edi: 0x00000020  esi: 0x00000003  ebp: 0xb0616cb8  esp:0xb0616c7c
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00d7d2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000206


Thread 6 crashed:

#  1  0x02c70c2a in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x958e68cb in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0xffffffff in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x9a07252e in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x91105bc4 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x94e6723c in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x94d8b288 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x94dafa65 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  9  0x00548102 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 10  0x0050a1d0 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 11  0x00502a8c in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 12  0x00482f5a in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 13  0x00487212 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 14  0x002433fb in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 15  0x0022d6c4 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 16  0x0022d928 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 17  0x0022f1ba in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 18  0x004b931d in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 19  0x02c94330 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 20  0x99294c4d in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 21  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 22  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0x02c70c20  ebx: 0x02c70b2d  ecx: 0xb071952c  edx:0x9a00fea2
 edi: 0x02c7ab88  esi: 0x00000007  ebp: 0xb07195a8  esp:0xb0719560
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x02c70c2a   cs: 0x0000001b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00010212


Thread 7:

#  1  0x9a00f8e2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x959850e0 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x9a19b4b8 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x9a3b2f63 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x9a19943c in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x9a3c88a0 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0x00000131  ebx: 0x0000a800  ecx: 0xb030ae4c  edx:0x9a00f8e2
 edi: 0x0000a701  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xb030aed8  esp:0xb030ae4c
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00f8e2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000202


Thread 8:

#  1  0x9a00f8e2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x95985095 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x9a31daa6 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x9a31d99e in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x9a19943c in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x9a3c88a0 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0x00000131  ebx: 0x00001200  ecx: 0xb0490e2c  edx:0x9a00f8e2
 edi: 0x00001000  esi: 0x00001000  ebp: 0xb0490eb8  esp:0xb0490e2c
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00f8e2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000202


Thread 9:

#  1  0x9a00f8e2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x95985095 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x9a31daa6 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x9a31d99e in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x9a19943c in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x9a3c88a0 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0x00000131  ebx: 0x00001300  ecx: 0xb081ee2c  edx:0x9a00f8e2
 edi: 0x00001000  esi: 0x00001000  ebp: 0xb081eeb8  esp:0xb081ee2c
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00f8e2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000202


Thread 10:

#  1  0x9a00f8e2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x95985095 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x9a31daa6 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x9a31d99e in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x9a19943c in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x9a3c88a0 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0x00000131  ebx: 0x00001100  ecx: 0xb08a0e2c  edx:0x9a00f8e2
 edi: 0x00001001  esi: 0x00001000  ebp: 0xb08a0eb8  esp:0xb08a0e2c
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00f8e2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000202


Thread 11:

#  1  0x9a00d7d2 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  2  0x94da5f79 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  3  0x94dab95f in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  4  0x94dab01a in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  5  0x94daae8b in  + 0x0000E7F0 ( + 0x00000000)
#  6  0x90fdf37a in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  7  0x91043448 in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  8  0x910433cb in  ( + 0x00000000)
#  9  0x958fa5b7 in  ( + 0x00000000)
# 10  0x958e4d4e in  ( + 0x00000000)

X86 Thread State:
 eax: 0xffffffe1  ebx: 0xb0922030  ecx: 0xb0921f2c  edx:0x9a00d7d2
 edi: 0x00000c00  esi: 0x07000006  ebp: 0xb0921f68  esp:0xb0921f2c
  ss: 0x00000023  eip: 0x9a00d7d2   cs: 0x0000000b   ds:0x00000023
  es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f  eflags:0x00000206


Loaded modules:


Operating System Information
Operating System: Mac OS X 10.8.4 (Build 12E55)
CPU: Intel Core Duo, Number: 4, Speed: 2147 MHz
gestaltPhysicalRAMSizeInMegabytes err = 0, result = 4096 MB
gestaltSystemVersion err = 0, result = 0x1084
Screen: 1280 x 800, depth = 32, ltbr = 0, 0, 800, 1280

Microsoft Application Information:
Error Reporting UUID: 4E4FB8F6-8F64-40D7-A076-8AA26D7D64EB
Time from launch: 0 hours, 3 minutes, 29 seconds
Total errors on this client: 8
```

Comment: unfortunately your crash log is somewhat useless without the symbols. have you tried starting out in Safe Mode? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2409331

Answer (score 2):

Try [rebuilding the Outlook database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2360509).

> Quit all applications.
>
> Make sure that you have enough HD space for a duplicate identity.
>
> Back up your current identity, located in `/Documents/Microsoft User Data`.
>
> Open Outlook while holding down the `Option` key.
>
> In the Microsoft Database Utility, select the identity you want to rebuild, and click the `Rebuild...` button.

Comment: Dave, thanks for such a prompt response, the links in addition to your guidance were the perfect combination. After a heart-stopping moment where I thought I'd lost my emails, I re-linked Outlook to the Exchange and all was well.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've had the same issues with Outlook users in my environment (which is why we use other mail clients now!)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David about rebuilding the database.  Although I haven't experienced this exact issue I have encountered many problems w/ Outlook 2011 and I'm always able to clear them up by rebuilding the database.

If David's directions aren't clear enough do a search for 'rebuild Outlook 2011 database' and you should find what you need.  Best of luck.